# OpenCV videocapture for large files

Tags: opencv, avi, large-file-support

I am using OpenCV 2.4.3 with my own 64-bit binaries that are also built with QT 4.8.3.  I am using DirectShow for videocapture and recently encountered a problem that I am unable to solve.  Namely, the following code works perfectly on uncompressed .avi files smaller than 2043 frames.

```
VideoCapture src = "D:/TestVideo/BigFile.avi";
Mat img;
while( src.read(img) )
{
 imshow("Input", img);
 waitKey(30);  
}
```

However, src.read(img) returns false on the 2043rd frame.

It does this on different Windows 7, 64-bit platforms and with all .avi files larger than 2043 frames.  I doubt that it matters but  the videos are 640x480, 8 bits, 1 and 3 channels.

Has anyone seen this problem before and can you recommend a solution?

Thanks,
TR

Comment: Does it do this for all videos captured by DirectShow or for all videos in general? If it does it for all videos, I would suggest to try using any pre-built binaries either for 2.4.3 or for a previous version just to test if indeed this is the problem; fyi it runs fine for me: Windows 7, 64-bit, prebuilt 2.2, random large avi

Comment: Thanks Bob.  Your suggestion did not work for me, directly.   It did, however, help isolate the issue.  I tried the code in a simple console application, with pre-built and my own binaries, and it works fine.  Duplicating the code in a simple Win32 test application also worked.  Therefore, the problem seems related to the implementation within my larger Windows application.  TR